# EntityFramework Core: Navigation was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities in DB with many-to-many relationship and additional table:

```
    public class Tour: IBaseEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? MainText { get; set; }
        public int? MaxNumberOfClients { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfClients { get; set; }
        public int? Rating { get; set; }
        public int? Cost { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfEnd { get; set; }
        public string? MainImageUrl { get; set; }

        public Guid TypeOfTransportId { get; set; }
        public virtual TypeOfTransport? TypeOfTransport { get; set; }

        public virtual List<TourCountry>? TourCountries { get; set; }
        public virtual List<UserTour>? UsersTours { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Country : IBaseEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<TourCountry>? TourCountries { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class TourCountry : IBaseEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid TourId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tour Tour { get; set; }

        public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    }
```

When I trying to add any migration with changes in DB I have an exeption:

```
Navigation 'GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TourCountry (Dictionary<string, object>).Tours' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.
```

What the reason of this problem and how to solve it?

I try to found the reason in DbContextModelSnapshot, but didn't see anything:

```
[DbContext(typeof(GoodTripDbContext))]
    partial class GoodTripDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.9")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Comment", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<DateTime?>("DateOfCreation")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<string>("Text")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<Guid>("UserId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("UserId");

                    b.ToTable("Comments");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Country", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Countries");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Role", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Roles");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Tour", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<int?>("Cost")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<DateTime?>("DateOfEnd")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<DateTime?>("DateOfStart")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("MainText")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int?>("MaxNumberOfClients")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int?>("NumberOfClients")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<int?>("Rating")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<Guid>("TypeOfTransportId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("TypeOfTransportId");

                    b.ToTable("Tours");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TourCountry", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<Guid>("CountryId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<Guid>("TourId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("CountryId");

                    b.HasIndex("TourId");

                    b.ToTable("TourCountries");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TypeOfTransport", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("TypesOfTransports");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<string>("Address")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Email")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("PasswordHash")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("PhoneNumber")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<Guid?>("RoleId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("RoleId");

                    b.ToTable("Users");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.UserTour", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<DateTime?>("DateOfCreation")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<Guid>("TourId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<Guid>("UserId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("TourId");

                    b.HasIndex("UserId");

                    b.ToTable("UsersTours");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Comment", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.User", "User")
                        .WithMany("Comments")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("User");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Tour", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TypeOfTransport", "TypeOfTransport")
                        .WithMany("Tours")
                        .HasForeignKey("TypeOfTransportId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("TypeOfTransport");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TourCountry", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Country", "Country")
                        .WithMany("TourCountries")
                        .HasForeignKey("CountryId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Tour", "Tour")
                        .WithMany("TourCountries")
                        .HasForeignKey("TourId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Country");

                    b.Navigation("Tours");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.User", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Role", "Role")
                        .WithMany("Users")
                        .HasForeignKey("RoleId");

                    b.Navigation("Role");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.UserTour", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Tour", "Tour")
                        .WithMany("UsersTours")
                        .HasForeignKey("TourId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.User", "User")
                        .WithMany("UsersTours")
                        .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Tour");

                    b.Navigation("User");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Country", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("TourCountries");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Role", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("Users");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Tour", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("TourCountries");

                    b.Navigation("UsersTours");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TypeOfTransport", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("Tours");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("Comments");

                    b.Navigation("UsersTours");
                });
```

Can someone to help with this problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TourCountry` class definition, there's no navigation property named `Tours`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TourCountry", b =>
{
    // ...
    b.Navigation("Country");
    b.Navigation("Tours"); // Wrong one
});
```

You should update the navigation property from `"Tours"` to `"Tour"`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TourCountry", b =>
{
    // ...
    b.Navigation("Country");
    b.Navigation("Tour");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a typo here:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.TourCountry", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Country", "Country")
                        .WithMany("TourCountries")
                        .HasForeignKey("CountryId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasOne("GoodTrip.DataBase.Entities.Tour", "Tour")
                        .WithMany("TourCountries")
                        .HasForeignKey("TourId")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.Navigation("Country");

                    // b.Navigation("Tours");
                    // Should actually be:
                    b.Navigation("Tour");
                });
```

Comment: Amit Mohanty, akseli - thank's, your advice are correct, everything worked for now)))

Comment: @RamanShuliak maybe mark the answer as accepted so that other users can also benefit in case they run into similar issues.